# Deprecation warning mystery: only jobs and cronjob trigger a warning for a manually created token

Tags: kubernetes

I have upgraded a kubernetes cluster from 1.26.x to 1.27.x

And now every time I try to create an object of `CronJob` or `Job` type - I get the following warning message:

```
Warning: Use tokens from the TokenRequest API or manually created secret-based tokens instead of auto-generated secret-based tokens.
```

What I have: a service account

What I have done:

1. Created a new secret with a `kubernetes.io/service-account.name` annotation reference
2. Removed the default `<sa-name>-token-xxxx` secret
3. Checked that `sa.<sa-name>.secrets` is empty now

Yet, I still receive the warning.

I checked source code: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/0241da314e0e69817d66313b45a69c19d1ce7327/pkg/serviceaccount/legacy.go#L152

From there it looks like not having a secret in .secrets should be enough, yet it's not.

I additionally restarted everything just to ensure nothing is cached somewhere.

And somehow it is specific to jobs/cronjobs only: creating orphaned pods, deploys, services, ingresses works fine; but creating jobs and cronjobs - triggers the warning.

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `kubectl` cache is to blame.

Hence clearing the `~/.kube/cache` resolved the problem.